# Trying to filter classes

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to filter google maps markers that have certain css classes's.

The markers can have tag's ,categories, type's and a time class attached to them.

for example a markers has the css classes : tag1,tag2,cat1,type2,time1

I want to be able to filter the markers, so I'm trying to write a jquery selector that only show's the right markers.

An example of an filter would be, show all markers that have tag1 OR tag2 AND cat2 AND time1

I can't seem to find any documentation for using AND and OR's in a jquery selector. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comma separation instead of `or` between two selectors and then further filter the results:

```
var selection = $('.tag1, .tag2').filter('.cat2.time1');
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.tag1,.tag2.cat2.time1')
```

Comment: This will select `$('.tag1')` and `$('.tag2.cat2.time1')`.

I assume the OP wanted (.tag1 OR .tag2) AND (.cat2.time1)